# Traefik - redirect when URL is not xxx?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to deploy sites using Traefik and keep my `docker-compose.yml` fairly clean. It's typical to have a website that has a primary domain - *example.com* - but a handful of aliases (e.g. *anotherdomain.com*, *differentdomain.com*).

I'd like to do a rule in Traefik to redirect to my canonical domain if accessed by an alias. Something like:

```
- "traefik.http.routers.http.rule=Host(`example.com`, `www.example.com`, `anotherdomain.com`, `www.anotherdomain.com`, `differentdomain.com`, `www.differentdomain.com`)"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.root-to-canonical.redirectregex.regex=!^https://www.example.com/(.*)"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.root-to-canonical.redirectregex.replacement=https://www.example.com/$${1}"
- "traefik.http.routers.http.middlewares=root-to-canonical"
```

However, I can't quite get the syntax right to handle it. Does anyone have a working example?

Comment: Sadly, I don't believe this is currently possible.  I could not find a capability within go regular expressions to achieve this, and traefik's redirectregex doesn't appear to support negation either.  I had to spell out all my alias domains in the regex, i.e. (domain1|domain2|domain3).

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up doing a similar thing to you.